# Format of timesince filter

Tags: django, django-templates

Is there a way to use the `{{date|timesince}}` filter, but instead of having two adjacent units, only display one?

For example, my template is currently displaying "18 hours, 16 minutes". How would I get it to display "18 hours"? (Rounding is not a concern here.) Thank you.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

I can't think of a simple builtin way to do this. Here's a custom filter I've sometimes found useful:

```
from django import template
from django.template.defaultfilters import stringfilter

register = template.Library()

@register.filter
@stringfilter
def upto(value, delimiter=None):
    return value.split(delimiter)[0]
upto.is_safe = True
```

Then you could just do

```
{{ date|timesince|upto:',' }}
```

Comment: Seems like `delimiter` shouldn't be an optional argument. You might as well give it a sensible default, like ','.

Comment: @AndrewB. The default behaviour for `split` is to split on whitespace, and it does the same thing when passed `None`

Comment: I want to make "1h 23min" instead of "1 hour 23 minutes",
how can i do it?
Also what should i name the file?
(I didn't undersand how the code works above)

Answer (score 5):

Since the [timesince](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/?from=olddocs#timesince) filter doesn't accept any arguments, you will have to manually strip off the hours from your date.

Here is a [custom template filter](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/howto/custom-template-tags/) you can use to strip off the minutes, seconds, and microseconds from your datetime object:

```
#this should be at the top of your custom template tags file
from django.template import Library, Node, TemplateSyntaxError
register = Library()

#custom template filter - place this in your custom template tags file
@register.filter
def only_hours(value):
    """
    Filter - removes the minutes, seconds, and milliseconds from a datetime

    Example usage in template:

    {{ my_datetime|only_hours|timesince }}

    This would show the hours in my_datetime without showing the minutes or seconds.
    """
    #replace returns a new object instead of modifying in place
    return value.replace(minute=0, second=0, microsecond=0)
```

If you haven't used a custom template filter or tag before, you will need to create a directory in your django application (i.e. at the same level as models.py and views.py) called `templatetags`, and create a file inside it called `__init__.py` (this makes a standard python module).

Then, create a python source file inside it, for example `my_tags.py`, and paste the sample code above into it. Inside your view, use `{% load my_tags %}` to get Django to load your tags, and then you can use the above filter as shown in the documentation above.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can make use of JS here. You need to add a script that splits the first and second units and then displays only the first one.

Say the part of your template looks like this:

```
<your_tag id="your_tag_id">{{date|timesince}}</your_tag>
```

Now, add the below script to your template.

```
<script>
        let timesince = document.getElementById("your_tag_id").innerHTML.split(",");
        document.getElementById("your_tag_id").innerHTML = timesince[0];
</script>
```

Answer (score -3):

A quick and dirty way:

Change the django source file $PYTHON_PATH/django/utils/timesince.py @line51(django1.7) :

```
result = avoid_wrapping(name % count)
return result  #add this line let timesince return here
if i + 1 < len(TIMESINCE_CHUNKS):
    # Now get the second item
    seconds2, name2 = TIMESINCE_CHUNKS[i + 1]
    count2 = (since - (seconds * count)) // seconds2
    if count2 != 0:
        result += ugettext(', ') + avoid_wrapping(name2 % count2)
return result
```

Comment: Probably better to just copy it and make your own version, a little less quick but much less dirty.