# Django built-in timesince filter to show only Days

Tags: python, django, django-template-filters

I am using `{{ prospect.date_1 }} - ({{ prospect.date_1|timesince }} ago)` in my template to get time since the date.

The point is, date_1 is a `date` not `datetime`, so when i apply the filter it tells me like

`July 18, 2014 - (11 hours, 39 minutes ago)`

### expected output

`July 18, 2014 - (0 days ago)`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6481909/1517648 may answer your question.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to display "x days ago" type time using Humanize in Django template?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6494921/how-to-display-x-days-ago-type-time-using-humanize-in-django-template)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

taken from [naturalday](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/humanize/templatetags/humanize.py#L159)

```
@register.filter(expects_localtime=True)
def days_since(value, arg=None):
    try:
        tzinfo = getattr(value, 'tzinfo', None)
        value = date(value.year, value.month, value.day)
    except AttributeError:
        # Passed value wasn't a date object
        return value
    except ValueError:
        # Date arguments out of range
        return value
    today = datetime.now(tzinfo).date()
    delta = value - today
    if abs(delta.days) == 1:
        day_str = _("day")
    else:
        day_str = _("days")

    if delta.days < 1:
        fa_str = _("ago")
    else:
        fa_str = _("from now")

    return "%s %s %s" % (abs(delta.days), day_str, fa_str)
```

results

```
>>> days_since(datetime.now())
'0 days ago'
>>> days_since(date(2013, 5, 12))
'432 days ago'
>>> days_since(date(2014, 12, 12))
'147 days from now'
>>> days_since(date(2014, 7, 19))
'1 day from now'
```

Comment: @Jack You're welcome. There was a tiny bug in that answer, please see my edit.

Answer (score 0):

@Jack, Have you tried to use in-built python:

Visit: https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.day

Also if this might help:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/contrib/humanize/#naturaltime

### Edit:

```
from datetime import date
from datetime import datetime
d = date.today()
datetime.combine(d, datetime.min.time())
```

Comment: please donot provide link only answers.please try to explain question in your words here :)

Comment: date_1 is a date object. but let me try that.

Comment: {{ prospect.date_1 }} - ({{ prospect.date_1.day }} ago) ==== July 18, 2014 - (18 ago)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @sundarnatarajСундар..:)..I'll take cake of it in future.

Comment: @Jack...Either you can convert your date object to datetime object. I have edited my answer!